# Как сверстать отличающиеся главную и внутреннюю страницы для Joomla 3

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

Надо  сверстать отличающиеся главную и внутреннюю страницы для Joomla. 
Обычно для того чтобы отличался дизайн на главной и внутренней странице используют 2 шаблона (просто на главную назначают другой шаблон, нежели на внутренние), но в моем случае не вижу смысла делать другой шаблон, так как они отличаются только в header'e

Макет главной: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Макет внутренной: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

что-то вроде такого

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    //вывод хэдера главной страницы
} else {
    //вывод хэдера остальных страниц
}
?>
```

проверяете, является ли текущая страница главной, и в зависимости от этого выводите в шаблоне нужный хэдер. проверки для разных версий джумлы можно тут посмотреть https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page

Comment: Если в joomla есть такое понятие, как layout, то лучше использовать его.